# Central speaker playing the subwoofer sound, and subwoofer playing central speaker sound

Tags: sound, speakers

I've a C-Media sound card - CM8738 and 5.1 speakers.

Everything seems to work pretty good, but there is a problem - two speakers are mixed - subwoofer is a central speaker, and central speaker is a subwoofer for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

1- Run in terminal  `gksu gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf`
This is the file where the channel map is, enter you pasword when prompted, and the file will open.

2- You are looking for the code that looks like this-

```
[Mapping analog-surround-51]
 device-strings = surround51:%f
 channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
 paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker analog-output-desktop-speaker analog-output-lfe-on-mono
 priority = 8
 direction = output
```

3- It may not be exactly the same, but we want to change only the channel-map order
from -
  `channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe`
  to  -
  `channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,lfe,front-center`

Notice the order on lfe and front-center, lfe is the subwoofer, and front-center is your center speaker, if it displays another configuration, just swap position of `lfe` and `front-center`

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1484966.html

Let me know how this works for your version.

Comment: Now pulseaudio don't want to work. Sound settings don't see any sound card.

Comment: I did. Ubuntu 12.04, but it didn't worked on previous versions also. I don't have amplituner, it's normal sound system from Creative so I guess, I will have to buy new sound card. Bad news. But I still have some hope.

Comment: It is probably not possible to map output jacks as input jacks with this method, is it? I tried, but the mic still seems not to be connected/existing in the Unity audio settings...

Comment: It works for Opensuse Tumbleweed with my unpretentious CSL sound card